How to plot smith chart using pysmithplot
Please help me with a pysmithplot. I copied the example below from another Stackoverflow posted a few years ago:
# I changed pylab to pyplot below
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import smithplot
from smithplot import SmithAxes

fig = plt.figure() 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121) 
ax1.plot([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)]) 
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, label = "a", projection='smith') 
plt.show()

I was expecting the following image but got an error.

Here is the trace back below. I am executing this in Jupyter Lab.

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
last) Cell In[3], line 8 6 ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)  7 ax1.plot([(1,
2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)])  8 ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, label =
"a", projection='smith')  9 plt.show()
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:782,
in FigureBase.add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs) 780         args =
tuple(map(int, str(args[0]))) 781     projection_class, pkw =
self._process_projection_requirements(**kwargs) 782     ax =
projection_class(self, *args, **pkw) 783     key = (projection_class,
pkw) 784 return self._add_axes_internal(ax, key)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\smithplot\smithaxes.py:376,
in SmithAxes.init(self, *args, **kwargs) 373 self.scParams =
self.scDefaultParams.copy() 375 # seperate Axes parameter 376
Axes.init(self, *args, **SmithAxes.update_scParams(instance=self,
filter_dict=True, reset=False, **kwargs)) 377 self.set_aspect(1,
adjustable='box', anchor='C') 379 # remove all ticks
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py:678,
in _AxesBase.init(self, fig, facecolor, frameon, sharex, sharey,
label, xscale, yscale, box_aspect, *args, **kwargs) 675
self.set_axisbelow(mpl.rcParams['axes.axisbelow']) 677
self._rasterization_zorder = None 678 self.clear() 680 # funcs used to
format x and y - fall back on major formatters 681 self.fmt_xdata =
None
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py:1386,
in _AxesBase.clear(self) 1383 # Act as an alias, or as the superclass
implementation depending on the 1384 # subclass implementation. 1385
if self._subclass_uses_cla: 1386     self.cla() 1387 else: 1388
self.__clear()
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\smithplot\smithaxes.py:422,
in SmithAxes.cla(self) 420 self.grid = dummy 421 # Don't forget to
call the base class 422 Axes.cla(self) 423 self.grid = tgrid 425
self._normbox = None
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py:1395,
in _AxesBase.cla(self) 1392 # Act as an alias, or as the superclass
implementation depending on the 1393 # subclass implementation. 1394
if self._subclass_uses_cla: 1395     self.__clear() 1396 else: 1397
self.clear()
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py:1356,
in _AxesBase.__clear(self) 1353 self.set_axis_on() 1355
self.xaxis.set_clip_path(self.patch) 1356
self.yaxis.set_clip_path(self.patch) 1358 if self._sharex is not None:
1359     self.xaxis.set_visible(xaxis_visible)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_api\deprecation.py:297,
in rename_parameter..wrapper(*args, **kwargs)   292
warn_deprecated( 293         since, message=f"The {old!r} parameter of
{func.name}() " 294         f"has been renamed {new!r} since
Matplotlib {since}; support " 295         f"for the old name will be
dropped %(removal)s.") 296     kwargs[new] = kwargs.pop(old) 297
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1111,
in Axis.set_clip_path(self, path, transform) 1108
@_api.rename_parameter("3.8", "clippath", "path") 1109 def
set_clip_path(self, path, transform=None): 1110
super().set_clip_path(path, transform) 1111     for child in
self.majorTicks + self.minorTicks: 1112
child.set_clip_path(path, transform) 1113     self.stale = True
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:591, in
_LazyTickList.get(self, instance, owner) 589 else: 590     instance.minorTicks = [] 591     tick =
instance._get_tick(major=False) 592
instance.minorTicks.append(tick) 593     return instance.minorTicks
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:1562,
in Axis._get_tick(self, major) 1558     raise NotImplementedError(
1559         f"The Axis subclass {self.class.name} must define
" 1560         "_tick_class or reimplement _get_tick()") 1561 tick_kw
= self._major_tick_kw if major else self._minor_tick_kw 1562 return self._tick_class(self.axes, 0, major=major, **tick_kw)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:480, in
YTick.init(self, *args, **kwargs) 477 self.gridline.set( 478
data=([0, 1], [0, 0]), transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform("grid")) 479 #
the y loc is 3 points below the min of y axis 480 trans, va, ha =
self._get_text1_transform() 481 self.label1.set( 482     x=0, y=0, 483
verticalalignment=va, horizontalalignment=ha, transform=trans, 484 )
485 trans, va, ha = self._get_text2_transform()
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py:492, in
YTick._get_text1_transform(self) 491 def _get_text1_transform(self):
492     return self.axes.get_yaxis_text1_transform(self._pad)
File
~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\smithplot\smithaxes.py:512,
in SmithAxes.get_yaxis_text1_transform(self, pixelPad) 510 def
get_yaxis_text1_transform(self, pixelPad): 511     if hasattr(self,
'yaxis') and len(self.yaxis.majorTicks) > 0: 512         font_size =
self.yaxis.majorTicks[0].label.get_size() 513     else: 514
font_size = self._get_key("font.size")
AttributeError: 'YTick' object has no attribute 'label'

